# How to create layouts where everything is resized to remain visible (no scroll bar)?

Tags: layout, vuetify.js, responsive, viewport

I am trying to build a web application without page overflow (everything contained in the viewport).
There must be something stupid I don't understand or missed, but if I try to create a very simple layout like we would do in a desktop application with some controls on top and a listbox at the bottom, the listbox overflows.

I could do all the height calculations myself, but I can't believe there isn't an easier way.
Also, I don't want to specify fixed heights. I want the application to be resizable.

Here's a snippets that demonstrates the problem. In my real case scenario, the v-select in the example is replaced by an arbitrary component with arbitrary height. I want the v-list below it to take whatever available space there is and have its own scrollbar.

```
<template>
<v-responsive height="100vh" contain>
  <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
    <v-col class="fill-height" cols="2">
      <v-select></v-select>
      <v-list class="fill-height">
        <v-list-item v-for="n in 30" :key="n">
            <v-list-item-title>Item {{ n }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-col>
  </v-container>
</v-responsive>
</template>
```

Here's what it looks like when I resize the browser window. Notice the listbox expanding outside the viewport.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c90f3.png)

I need to be able to use a v-list that will take whatever space is left for it.
Is there a way to do that?
I tried so many things and nothing seems to work. I would appreciate any advice from the experts here ;-)